# Possible correction to a question about series and convergence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Let $(a_j)$ be a sequence with positive terms. There exists $a>0$ such that $a_{j+1}/a_j=1-a/j+r_j$, where $r_j/j\to 0$ as $j\to \infty$.

A question on my book ask me to prove that if $a>1$, then the series $\sum a_j$ converges, but this is clearly not ture. Let $a=2$ and $r_j=\sqrt j$ for $j\geq 10$. Then there exists a sequence such that the ratio $1-a/j+r_j>1$ for all $j>10$, which means the series $\sum a_j$ diverges.

**EDIT:** I am perhaps being a bit unclear, but there is no misunderstanding here about $\exists $ and $\forall$. I write the above solution in such a way that it looks like $\forall a$, but actually it does not matter. Here is a clearer version:

Let $a_k=a_{10}\prod_{j=10}^{k-1} (1-2/j+\sqrt j)$. Then there exists $a>1$, for example $a=2$, such that $a_{j+1}/a_j=1-a/j+r_j$, $r_j/j \to 0$.

How could I fix this question so that it becomes a correct result?

Comment: Are you sure that it is wrong? From what I can understand of the question, it says - 'For every sequence, $\exists$ a an $a$'. Nowhere is it said that '$\forall a$, $\exists$ a corresponding sequence for which the property holds', which is what you are assuming when you take the case $a=2$, and assume that $\exists$ a sequence of positive terms associated with it.

Comment: @IshanDeo See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

Neither the problem statement nor your solution is entirely clear. The constant $a$ is introduced under the scope of an existential quantifier (“There exists $a$”) and then later referred to outside of that scope (“if $a\gt1$” in the problem statement, “Let $a=2$” in your solution). It’s not clear whether what’s meant in the problem statement is “if this statement holds for some $a\gt1$” or “if all $a$ for which this statement holds are $\gt1$”.

In any case, in the current formulation, the truth of the statement is independent of $a$. It looks like the equation was perhaps meant to read $a_{j+1}/a_j=1-a/j+r_j/j$. Note that for $a_{j+1}/a_j=1-a/j$ we would have $a_j\sim j^{-a}$, so in this case the series would indeed converge for $a\gt1$.

Comment: Thank you. I have edited my solution, to make the quantifiers more obvious.